# django threadedcomments

Tags: python, django, comments, blogs

I would like to setup a comment systems on my site, using django threadedcomments, and I follow all the steps in the Tutorial, however, I get the following error:

**No module named newforms.util**

I am not sure what causing this issue, here is my configuration:

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',    
    'myproject.myapp',
    'threadedcomments',    
)


#urls.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^threadedcomments/', include('threadedcomments.urls')),
)
```

Please let me know if there is another better choice for commenting, as long as the comment system is flexible and able to do lot of customization, as well as threadedcomment, of coz, integrating with Rating, I am happy to use the other one.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

You are most probably using a very old version of one of your apps. The `newforms` module has disappeared from django a long time ago.

Comment: yes, I am using python 2.6 and Django version: (1, 1, 1, 'final', 0), so is there any other comments system I can use, or I should modify the newforms to "from django import forms".....is there any other better comments system?

Comment: Look for any occurrence of "newforms" in your whole project and remove the app that contains it. It is just too old and won't work with django 1.1.1. Depending on which app it is, you might be able to download a newer version.

Comment: Is the offending import in threadedcomments itself? In which case, where did you get it? The version [here](http://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments) is up to date.

Comment: yes, the error is inside the threadedcomments itself. Is there any other blogging/commenting systems are good? I am developing on the Windows machine, seems Byteflow is quite good, but I don't know how to install in on my Windows machine actually.

Comment: Did you not read my comment? You are obviously using the wrong (extremely old) version of threadedcomments. See my link above.

Comment: yes, you are right Daniel. I have just downloaded the new version and will remove the "threadedcomments" in the "site-packages", is there any particular way to remove the python/django packages, or just delete the folder in the "site-packages" directory?

Comment: the threadedcomments documentation/tutorial is not really up-to-date, is there any better example/doc. can learn how to use the threadedcomments?